# Movie about a daydreamer child who loses her father

Tags: identify-this-movie

It saw only the beginning of this movie when I was a child. That means the production date cannot be after 1995. It is possibly a 70s/80s movie and colored. I saw the movie in Turkey but it is not a turkish movie, might be European or American.

The movie is about a girl who lives in a rural environment and is daydreaming a lot (absorbed in a fantasy world). Her father tells her fascinating stories about himself being a bank robber/criminal. One day the father dies in an accident, might be a car accident. She learns on that day that her father was not a bank robber, but a pediatrician (children doctor), or maybe a psychiatrist, in the city. She begins to face the reality first time in her life.

I haven't seen the rest of the film, because my mother didn't let me as it was late. I would be very gladful if someone has a clue.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [@LeonFreire](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/52511/leon-freire) the answer is found. There were some differences between the plot of the answer and my memory:

- The father doesn't die at the beginning, but leaves the family.
- He is not a psychiatrist, but a medical doctor. I should have
  thought (as a child) he was one because he uses a pendant in the
  movie.

Comment: Why downvoted? I have provided all information I remember.

Comment: Not my downvote, but there are several grammar mistakes in the question, some of them pretty severe, so maybe someone decided to just downvote, instead of trying to help by editing and improving the question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am not a native speaker. All corrections are welcome... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am currently doing some digging and will take a shot at this one. Tell me if I'm right! :)

How about [El Sur (1983)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084740/?ref_=kw_li_tt)?

> El Sur (The South) is the story of Estrella (Iciar Bollain), a little girl from Southern Spain who has been uprooted to the North. Estrella maintains a sentimentalized attachment to the region of her birth, an attachment manifested in her love for her father (Omero Antonutti). The girl's rose-colored memories are shattered when she learns that her beloved dad once carried on affair with a Southern woman-and that the flames of passion still smolder within him. This Spanish/Argentinian coproduction was filmed on location in Madrid, Navarre, Vittoria, and Zamora. ~ Hal Erickson, Rovi

Here is why I think this could be the one (take into consideration I'm digging after your information, and still haven't seen this one).

- It's from 1983
- I've looked for pictures, and it seems to contain a lot of rural area scenes
- Maybe the rural/city you described is what the movie presents as her travel between North and South Spain
- It is said that she has fond memories of her beloved father that are shattered when she learns of his affair. (Maybe this is when she *faces the reality*)

### EDIT

I've seen the trailer now, and I'm more convinced this guess is correct:

- The first few seconds already elaborate on the father's mistery and her illusions.
- At 0:50 the girl asks a elderly lady (perhaps grandmother) if it is true that her father was a criminal. This is very similar to what you described.

> - *Is it true that my father was a prisoner?*
> - *Who told you that?*

- Also it makes it very clear that she goes to the South to learn the truth, which looks more like a city.

---

[image: El Sur (1983)]

Comment: I will take a look as soon as I am home. I think this could really be it, and the differences might be caused by my lack of memory after years.

Comment: And I have read that the father is a medical doctor, I think this is it.

Comment: @Endery Nice. Let me know if its this one! :)

Comment: I have searched this movie like for 15 years and you have found it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Endery No problem! Glad to help! Hope it is everything you expected. I think I'll watch it too. Looks amazing. :)